# Nifi ConsumeKafka Fetch/Polling Query

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I have a ConsumeKafka processor that polls on a specified topic,

[image]

[image]

The idea is to pull from kafka topic and push it to InfluxDB.

My kafka topic retention period is 2 weeks. I have set my ConsumeKafka to fetch at **latest** offset.

However, sometimes I stop my ConsumeKafka processor, so in this case does the processor know the last state of the record that was fetched before the stop?

What happens when I play it after stopping? Do the records that came in the stopped time-frame get ignored?

Please provide some guidance as i'm very new to Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to is reset offset. Meaning, that if your consumer group was reset or not existed before, it will reset it to the latest offset. Since you don't reset your consumer group after stopping the processor, it will continue from the latest offset it has pulled, and not the latest offset ever until that point.